# C, get resource values in UNIX environment

Tags: c, unix, resources, posix, limit

In "Advanced programming in the UNIX environment", in Figure 7.16, in pr_limits function, the following two lines are written to show resource limit.

```
lim = limit.rlim_max;
printf("%10lld", lim);
```

my question is, why the value is first copied to lim variable and then it is printed, and why not directly not printed?

Comment: Perhaps there's a type-conversion involved? Reading [this Linux manual page of `getrlimit`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html) mentions that the Linux system calls uses a 32-bit `rlim_t` while the glibc wrapper function uses 64 bit. So perhaps the author wanted to make sure to use 64-bit types no matter the actual type of `limit.rlim_max`?

Comment: At the bottom of the page @Someprogrammerdude linked to you can see that they instead cast to the biggest integer type available: `if (prlimit(pid, RLIMIT_CPU, newp, &old) == -1) err(EXIT_FAILURE, "prlimit-1");`
`printf("Previous limits: soft=%jd; hard=%jd\n", (intmax_t) old.rlim_cur, (intmax_t) old.rlim_max);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my question is, why the value is first copied to lim variable and then it is printed, and why not directly not printed?

Probably as you have been pointed to in the comments, there's a conversion issue in the middle.  The linux man page states that

```
struct rlimit {
    rlim_t rlim_cur;  /* Soft limit */
    rlim_t rlim_max;  /* Hard limit (ceiling for rlim_cur) */
};
```

and `rlim_t` cannot be warranted to be a specific type, so to be portable, you can either use an intermediate variable to do the conversion (so you can safely use the `%10lld` format specifier) or you can use a cast in the call to `printf()` to ensure proper formatting.  Anyway, the use of an extra variable will probably be eliminated by the compiler in the optimization process, so you most probably will not sense any efficiency penalty.

This extra type conversion ensures portability of code.